# make background image of div move continuously

Tags: jquery, css

Here's the css I have for a div located in my `body` tag :

```
.background {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background: url('Queens-University.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100px 150px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
    -moz-filter: blur(2px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(3px);
}
```

I am trying to move the background image of this div move from left to right in a continuous manner (infinite).

I am trying to do this using jQuery but nothing is happening, here is my code:

```
$(window).load(function() { 
    var image = $('.background');
    var x=0;
    setInterval(function(){
        image.css('background-position', x + 'px 0');
        x++;
    }, 10);
});
```

How can I use the jQuery to move the background-image? What is wrong with my function?

Comment: `x` is always 0, try to sum 1 to it inside the interval

Comment: @kosmos I added x++ but it still does not work

Comment: Try with `backgroundPosition` instead of `background-position`

Comment: Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/dzaxsg6f/

Comment: @kosmos - works like a charm here - and thanks for letting me know of lorempixel.com - great resource...

Comment: @kosmos just what I needed. Still doesn't work for me, I'm probably loading my jQuery wrong, but thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

May I suggest, in the end of year 2015, another way, using CSS only.

```
@keyframes animatedBackground {
    from { background-position: 0 0; }
    to { background-position: 100% 0; }
}
#animate-area   { 
    width: 560px; 
    height: 400px; 
    background-image: url(bg-clouds.png);
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
}
```

Src: https://davidwalsh.name/demo/background-animation-css.php

Answer (score 2):

I've rewritten your jQuery script into plain vanilla javascript and it seems to work fine:

```js
function slideBackground() {

var background = document.getElementsByClassName('background')[0];
var x = 0;

setInterval(function(){
    background.style.backgroundPosition = x + 'px 0';
    x++;
    }, 10);

}

window.addEventListener('load',slideBackground,false);
```

```css
.background {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background: url('http://bit.ly/1NCb5xC');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100px 150px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
    -moz-filter: blur(2px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(3px);
}
```

```html
<div class="background">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You never seem to increment your `x` variable. It always has the value `0`...

Comment: You're right, I forgot to add `x++` but it still won't move

Answer (score 1):

The more jQuery'ish way of doing it, would be to write a plugin that animates the background

```
$.fn.animateBG = function(x, y, speed, callback) {
    var pos = this.css('background-position').split(' ');
    this.x  = pos[0] ? +pos[0].replace(/\D/g,'') : 0,
    this.y  = pos[1] ? +pos[1].replace(/\D/g,'') : 0,

    $.Animation( this, {
        x: x,
        y: y
    }, { 
        duration: speed
    }).progress(function(e) {
        this.css('background-position', e.tweens[0].now+'px '+e.tweens[1].now+'px');
    }).done(callback);

    return this;
};
```

And then just use it in a recursive function for infinite animation

```
(function recursive() {
    $('.background').animateBG(100, 0, 1000, function() {
        this.animateBG(0, 0, 1000, recursive);
    });
}());
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/dzaxsg6f/1/)

Answer (score 0):

First, jquery use another format for CSS. It's `backgroundPosition` instead of `background-position`.

Second point, instead of call a timeout every 10sec, call .animate() function. Something like:

```
setInterval(function() {
  $('.background').animate({backgroundPosition: imageWidth + ' 0'}, 1000);
}, 1000);
```

Third: You never increment `x`.. Do a x++ on your SetTimeout.

Comment: In jQuery `.css()` method `'background-position'` and `backgroundPosition` work as expected.